# Are HTML script elements allowed to be external even when in the body?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML, are `<script>` elements allowed to be external and use `<script src="myscript.js">` even when in the `<body>` of the document?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This is how a lot of widgets work like Google Maps. Make sure you specify the type though:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought you should specify the type even for scripts in the head section. Or is it somehow special for scripts inside the body?

Comment: You should always specify the type :)

Comment: If using HTML5, you don't need to the `type` attribute, it defaults to `text/javascript`.